# Second order nonlinear ODE with a squared first derivative

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

In the context of an [HJB equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamilton%E2%80%93Jacobi%E2%80%93Bellman_equation) for a control problem that I'm trying to solve, I have encountered the following ODE
$$
 4 \gamma  \zeta ^2 \beta  g(x) = \zeta ^2 \left(2 \gamma  \sigma ^2 x^2 g''(x)+1\right)-2 \zeta  g'(x) \left(\rho +2 \gamma  \zeta  x \left(\mu -\rho -\sigma ^2\right)\right)+\rho ^2 g'(x)^2\ .
$$
where Greek letters are constants. Setting each of these equal to unity simplifies the above to
$$
 4 g(x)=2 x^2 g''(x)+g'(x)^2+2 (2 x-1) g'(x)+1\ ,
$$
This latter ODE in fact admits the non-trivial solution $g(x) = x - 2 x^2$. Is there any way to apply this knowledge to full problem?

Comment: Not particularly useful but $g = 1/4$ is a solution:)

Comment: @KamalSaleh Have to tested this solution? Superposition is not possible for nonlinear differential equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More generally, consider the o.d.e.
$$A x^2 g''(x) + B [g(x)']^2 + (C x + D) g'(x) + E g(x) + F = 0 ,$$
where $A, \ldots, F$ are constants. In our case,
\begin{align}
A &= 2 \gamma \zeta^2 \sigma^2 \\
&\,\,\,\vdots \\
F &= \zeta^2 .
\end{align}

Provided that $E \neq 0$, we have the steady-state solution $g(x) = -\frac{F}{E}$ (in our case, $g(x) = \frac{1}{\beta \gamma}$.)

Notice that if $g$ is at most quadratic in $x$, so is the left-hand side of the differential equation, suggesting we take as ansatz a general quadratic polynomial: $g(x) = a x^2 + b x + c$. Substituting in the differential equation gives a system of $3$ quadratic equations in $a, b, c$:
\begin{align}
4 B a^2 + 2 A a + 2 C a + E a &= 0 \\
4 B a b + C b + 2 D a + E b &= 0 \\
B b^2 + D b + E c + F &= 0 ,
\end{align}
and solving the system is routine.
Provided that $B, 2 A + C, E$ are all nonzero, we have the solution
\begin{align}
a &= -\frac{2 A + 2 C + E}{4 B} \\
b &= -\frac{(2 A + 2 C + E) D}{2 (2 A + C) B} \\
c &= -\frac{16 A^2 B F - 4 A^2 D^2 + 16 A B C F - 4 A C D^2 + 4 B C^2 F + 2 C D^2 E + D^2 E^2}{4 (2 A + C)^2 B E} .
\end{align}
In our case, provided that $\beta, \gamma, \rho$, and $\alpha := \mu - \rho - 2 \sigma^2$ are all nonzero, we have the solution
$$
\boxed{g(x) =
\frac{(2 \alpha + \beta + \sigma^2) \gamma \zeta^2}{\rho^2} x^2
    + \frac{(2 \alpha + \beta + \sigma^2) \zeta}{\alpha \rho} x
    + \frac{(\alpha + \beta + \sigma^2)^2}{4 \alpha^2 \beta \gamma}} .$$

**Remark** The same observation applies and the same technique works even if we replace the coefficient of $g''(x)$ with an arbitrary quadratic function of $x$.

If $B = 0$ ($\rho = 0$), but $A \neq 0$ ($\gamma \sigma \zeta \neq 0$), the equation is second order and linear. Changing variable to $h(x) = x^\lambda g(x)$ for an appropriate constant $\lambda$ (depending on $A, C, E$) transforms the equation into [Kummer's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Confluent_hypergeometric_function#Kummer%27s_equation) in $h(x)$. If instead $A = B = 0$ ($\gamma \zeta \sigma = \rho = 0$), the equation is first order and linear.

If $E = 0$ ($\beta \gamma \zeta = 0$), the equation is a [Riccati equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Riccati_equation) in $f(x) := g'(x)$, so it can be converted into a linear, second-order o.d.e., and in this case it is possible to transform the equation in $f$ into [Whittaker's equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whittaker_function).

Comment: Excellent, thank you!

Comment: Hi, I just had a follow-up question. Above you locate what I think is the particular solution; could you say something about the general solution? I need to have the constants of integration in my case. Thanks.

Comment: Yes, the answer gives the unique quadratic solution (under the generic conditions on $\alpha, \beta, \gamma, \rho$. I don't see how to write down a general solution for arbitrary coefficients $\beta, \ldots, \sigma$---at that point we're already considering a broad class of second-order nonlinear o.d.e.s. One should be able to write down a general solution for the special cases $\rho = 0$ and $\beta \gamma \zeta = 0$ in terms of hypergeometric equations. You might also be able to say more in the case $2 A + C = 0$, which I didn't discuss in my answer.