# Second order nonlinear ODE with squared first derivative multiplied by $x^2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, reference-request

Similarly to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4830633/49082), I am looking for a method of solution for the following ODE with a squared first derivative term:
$$
\frac{1}{2}\sigma^2 x^2 g'' + \frac{\nu x^2 g'^2}{\eta^2} + \frac{(\alpha\eta+2\nu) x g'}{\eta} - \beta g + \nu = 0\ ,
$$
where the Greek letters are constants. The function $g(x) = \nu/\beta$ is a steady-state solution. I am looking for other, non-trivial solutions: I have tried guessing powers of $x$, but to no avail.

For ease of reference, if each of the constants is set to $1$, the above reduces to
$$
\frac{1}{2}x^2 g'' + x^2 g'^2 + 3 x g' - g + 1 = 0\ .
$$
Any hints or ideas are appreciated.